# Questions regarding flipping inequalities

Tags: inequality

Let ${s\geq 0,t\leq 0, s^2+t^2 \leq 1}$.

This gives us $0 \leq s \leq \sqrt{1-t^2}$. But what about $t$?

Wolframalpha gives $-\sqrt{1-s^2} \leq t \leq 0$. I do not understand the lower bound, because $s^2+t^2 \leq 1 => t \leq \sqrt{1-s^2}$. How do I flip the last inequality to find the lower bound of $t$? Should it not be $-t \geq -\sqrt{1-s^2}$?

Comment: @Sil Yes, I corrected my typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $\sqrt{a^2}=a$ holds only for $a \geq 0$, in general we have $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$, so for $a \leq 0$ it is actually $\sqrt{a^2}=-a$. (Remember, $\sqrt{a}$ is defined as the **non-negative** solution of $x^2=a$).

In your case we have $t^2\leq 1-s^2$, both sides are non-negative so this implies $\sqrt{t^2} \leq \sqrt{1-s^2}$, and since $t \leq 0$, we have $\sqrt{t^2}=-t$ and so $-t \leq \sqrt{1-s^2}$. Multiplying by $-1$ you get the expected result.

It is also worth noting that having $s \leq \sqrt{1-t^2}$ and $-\sqrt{1-s^2} \leq t$ at the same time is not very helpful, usually you have at least one free variable. For example you keep the $0 \leq s \leq \sqrt{1-t^2}$ inequalities, and for $t$ you know $t \leq 0$ and $1-t^2 \geq 0$, so $-1\leq t \leq 0$.